# Can I sort the items in repeated field collection of Google Protocol Buffer Builder?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I mean,

```
Collections.sort(myBuilder.getMyRepeatedItem(), myComparator);
```

Can I assume items will then be in the sorted order after calling `build()` later, or it is better to sort in a separate array and use `clearMyRepeatedItem()` and then `addAllMyRepeatedItem(...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that not even possible:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.sort(Collections.java:1331)
    at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
```

Sorry, I initially assumed may work but may not be recommended as something undocumented. However while you can add elements to the `Builder`, the list that the `Builder` returns is not a modifyable list.